# UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary in iOS 7 is not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

When I upgraded to iOS7, my app is showing an empty view controller when I access the photo Library from the application. It was working with older frameworks.

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker = imagePickerController;
    //self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please apply direct this code

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when this code run then "application" Would like to access your photos message come when you click on OK then all images will be displayed

Thanks.